# Не видит изменения JS

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed-insights

Не могу понять что не так, на локалхосте все ок работает, заливаю на прод и открывается старый код JS, абсолютно не видит нового файла. И в html ссылка такого вида `<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.js"></script>` а в просмотреть код страницы абракодабра

```
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.js+jquery.autocomplete.js+formOrder.js.pagespeed.jc.-3Oyph7LXK.js"></script>
```

Подскажите что это такое и как вылечить?
Вот тоже, что это переименовывает файлы?

```
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js+jquery.flexslider-min.js+jquery.mask.min.js+jquery.inputmask.min.js.pagespeed.jc.4478CMwBhg.js"></script><script>
```

Comment: На счет того, что отображается старый код после заливки на сервер, попробуйте почистить кэш браузера или перезгрузить страницу через ctrl+f5, а вот на счет абракадабры нужно подумать. Чем собираете ваш сайт?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin в смысле чем собираю? В notepad++ пишу и FileZilla отправляю на сервер. Я подумал что это pagespeed переименовывает ссылки в разметке